# What Shard Key Should I Choose for my MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I currently have a single MongoDB server running (in production). The largest collection in it is called User. This collection has a multikey (array) index. The dominant query against the User collection is an $or query against values in the multikey, indexed field. The other field in this collection is an array of PageViews.

As the server is becoming busier I'd like to shard it to ensure I continue to get the performance I'm currently getting out of it. The problem, of course, is choosing the shard key. Reading up on this it seems that I'm screwed for query isolation because of my multikey index and lack of other fields that could be included with the dominant query.

Various articles point out that it wouldn't be a good idea to create a shard key on a random value. This is because you lose out on query isolation. But, given that I'm unable to achieve good query isolation anyway, should I just shard on a random value?

Has anyone else been in this situation? Think of any good options?

Comment: Post your user collection structure and your query criteria for any suggestions

Comment: when you say "an $or query against values in multikey" do you mean an $in query?  Please post an example of a document and most common queries so that it's clear what the use case is.  It's also important to know how you write to the collection (i.e. how do you update the User document?)

Answer (score 0):

I have a plan that I think will work so I thought I'd share it back with the community.

In my scenario the multikey index field contains a number of items which are disambiguated by a prefix. The prefix indicates the type of the value stored in the multikey.

My solution will then be to figure out which item type is most frequently queried. In my scenario I know what this is and I would say that it is the item type queried more than 90% of the time. I'll then create another field in the document that stores the last value of an item of this type that has been saved to the multikey. I'll then use this new field as the shard key. Finally I'll change the application layer to first query on the new field. If that query fails I'll do a query on the multikey field. 90%+ of my queries should be query isolated. The rest will have to run on all the shards. Seems like a good compromise.

Comment: It turns out my idea did not work out after all. I hadn't realized that shard key values are immutable. So, my only solution now is to re-architect my data/application to not use a multikey at all. Painful but I will wind up with a perfect situation when I am done - my index field will also be my shard key. I will have query isolation, write distribution and high cardinality. For anyone that is in my situation I would suggest you don't reject re-architecting as a possible solution. Use the tool as it is meant to be used is probably the best idea.